# Meaning of goat-footed nature gods play in the fields and woods

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation

There,shepherds play their pipes and sigh with longing for flirtatious nymphs and goat-footed nature gods play in the fields and woods.
How can I understand this sentence? And does "play pipes" mean play some music instruments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There, shepherds play their pipes

[Pan pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_flute), an early flute. ([Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbWlYz9Zv5c))

> and sigh with longing for flirtatious nymphs and goat-footed nature gods

[Pan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_%28god%29) was a nature god. He had goat's feet.

> play in the fields and woods.

Comment: Further to this, ancient Greek and Roman myths had a couple types of nature gods that had goats feet. The [satyr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyr) and [faun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faun).

Answer (score 1):

Goat-footed has a dual meaning. The Greek god Pan had a human male head and torso and goat's horns, feet and tail. All the forest gods were lustful and drunken. This is probably where the slang word "horny" came from.

Goats are extremely nimble and can climb and descend steep,rocky paths without slipping. Sure-footed.